# Unable to use spannable string in setcenter text

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Mp android chart has a function called as `setdraecentertext()`, I want to set a spannable string inside that function and it is returning an error

`setCenterText(java.lang.String)` in `com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart` cannot be applied to `(android.text.SpannableString)`

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: `setCenterText()` method takes `java.lang.CharSequence` type as a parameter. So you can use any `String` or `SpannableString` to that method. Post your code for a better solution.